# Unable to load image from url

Tags: blackberry, httpconnection

I cannot load the image from url and play into my listfield

`ImageLoader` class

```java
public class Util_ImageLoader {
    public static Bitmap getImageFromUrl(String url) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        try {
            String bitmapData = getDataFromUrl(url);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmapFromBytes(bitmapData.getBytes(), 0,
                    bitmapData.length(), 1);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    private static String getDataFromUrl(String url) {
        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
        InputStream is = null;
        HttpConnection c = null;

        long len = 0;
        int ch = 0;

        try {
            c = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);

            is = c.openInputStream();
            len = c.getLength();
            if (len != -1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                    if ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
                        b.append((char) ch);
                    }
            } else {
                while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
                    len = is.available();
                    b.append((char) ch);
                }
            }

            is.close();
            c.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return b.toString();
    }
}
```

`ListField` class

```java
image = new BitmapField(Util_ImageLoader.getImageFromUrl(
    "http://www.orientaldaily.com.my/images/articles/4_APRIL_BLACK_copy.jpg"),
    Field.FIELD_HCENTER | Field.FIELD_VCENTER);
row.add(image);
field = getField(3);
layoutChild(field, 100, 80);
setPositionChild(field, getPreferredWidth() - 105, 5);
```

Comment: Are you using the debugger?  Any exceptions?  Which minimum version of the BlackBerry OS are you building this for (OS 5.0+, 6.0+, etc.)?

Comment: how to use debugger? cannot see exception because try catch already, i am using 7.0 SDK and minimum 1.0 but i want change it to 5.0 SDK if not my device cannot install

Comment: Are you using the BlackBerry JDE to build your software?  Or Eclipse with the BlackBerry plug-in?  Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add connection extension to Your Url.

like if wifi then **";interface=wifi"**

```
Example: c = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url+";interface=wifi");
```

Using perfect connection perameter

```
c = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url+getConnParam());
```

code sample for getting connection extension:

```
public static String getConnParam(){
        String connectionParameters = "";
        if (WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED) {
        // Connected to a WiFi access point
        connectionParameters = ";interface=wifi";
        } else {
        int coverageStatus = CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus();
        ServiceRecord record = getWAP2ServiceRecord();
        if (record != null
        && (coverageStatus & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) ==
        CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) {
        // Have network coverage and a WAP 2.0 service book record
        connectionParameters = ";deviceside=true;ConnectionUID="
        + record.getUid();
        } else if ((coverageStatus & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) ==
        CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) {
        // Have an MDS service book and network coverage
        connectionParameters = ";deviceside=false";
        } else if ((coverageStatus & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) ==
        CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) {
        // Have network coverage but no WAP 2.0 service book record
        connectionParameters = ";deviceside=true";
        }

    }
        return connectionParameters;
    }
```

reference urls:

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/javax/microedition/io/Connector.html#http

http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Different_ways_to_make_an_HTTP_or_socket_connection.html?nodeid=826935&vernum=0

Comment: `getWAP2ServiceRecord()` refer to what?

Answer (score 1):

I believe Alan said that he only needed to support OS 5.0 and above.  If that's true, then I would **not** recommend that he bother building connection *extension* strings, like `";interface=wifi"`.

OS 5.0 added the [ConnectionFactory class](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/transport/ConnectionFactory.html), which makes this much easier.

BlackBerry devices can make network requests with one of many different network *transports*.  Some apps care which transports are used.  Other apps just want any *available* transport.

For an example of using `ConnectionFactory` to [create a `Connection` with the first available transport, see this example](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11938/CS_create_first_available_HTTP_connection_857706_11.jsp)

For a more advanced example, that shows using the `ConnectionFactory` to specify a [list of transports to use first, and which to not use at all, see this example](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Sample-Code-Using-the-ConnectionFactory-class-in-a-BrowserField/ta-p/532860).

In the second example, the code is using a `BrowserField`, which Alan is not using.  But, he can replace his code

```java
c = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
```

With this

```java
c = (HttpConnection) MyConnectionFactory.getConnection(url).getConnection();
```

where `MyConnectionFactory` is [shown in the sample code](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Sample-Code-Using-the-ConnectionFactory-class-in-a-BrowserField/ta-p/532860).

Comment: i will still use `;interface=wifi` because now still using jre 7.0, However, soon i may change to 5.0 but i cannot change it although i downloaded jre 5.0

Comment: @AlanLai, you don't need to use `;interface=wifi` for any code that runs on OS 5.0 **or later**.  So, for OS 7.0, you definitely don't need to keep using connection suffix strings.  The `ConnectionFactory` is the recommended approach now.

Comment: The problem is if i not use then cannot display, but after apply it, it can display

Comment: @AlanLai, are you using the `ConnectionFactory` as I showed in the answer above?  Not `Connector.open(url);`.